# ttf-mscorefonts-installer tries to install in 16.04

Tags: upgrade

I've tried to install mscorefonts in 16.04, it failed, and now each time system boots a pop up appears saying that if failed and wanted to do again, I try but again it doesn't install, so the next time this pop up appears and so... What could I do for disabling it? Thanks

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo apt-get install -f` in a terminal? Also, can you provide us with some details? What went wrong? Do you have an error you could give us? In what way does the pop-up no complete the install: error or no response?

Comment: What would sudo apt-get install -f do? It doesn't show any error but the fonts don't appear and that pop up appears later again...

Comment: It's meant to fix any missing dependencies. Run `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` to try to install it again.

Comment: Installing the ubuntu-restricted-extras package in the last few releases of Ubuntu has got as far as the ttf-mscorefonts-installer before seeming to fail. A dialogue box should popup and ask you if you accept the terms of the licence for the ttf microsoft fonts and you'd have to agree to continue. Not sure of the reasons why it's been playing havoc with the Software Center but if you `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` as **Zacharee** suggests it should install & display the licence agreement in the terminal (Left/Right cursors keys to agree/disagree and enter/return to select)

Answer (score 24):

What you are seeing is probably the **download** part of the installer, which will keep trying indefinitely. This is because the location of the font files has been changed on Sourceforge, but the hard-coded location in the installer itself has not. There is a launchpad bug for this problem at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/1371783. Comment #45 in the bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/1371783/comments/45 explains what has happened.

The solution which worked for me (on a **clean** 16.04 install) and which resulted in the fonts being installed was:

```
# Due to a bug in ttf-mscorefonts-installer, this package must be downloaded from Debian at a later version and installed before the rest of the packages:
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
```

If you have already tried to install **ttf-mscorefonts-installer**, then it should be uninstalled first.

Comment: Comment #45 in the bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/1371783/comments/45 explains what has happened. **Currently** the font files have moved, and this seems to have been due to a previous syndrome which caused the bug. The bug has been kept as is since the headline is still correct, even though the underlying cause has changed.

@WinEunuuchs2Unix The solution given **does** work.

Comment: As I don't recall reading down to comment #45, I tried to up-vote to zero but the software wouldn't let me. I did delete my comment. You might want to leave your comment in case others review the answer as incorrect too.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem after installing Ubuntu 16.04 fresh and then installing Battle.net. Launching it gave the same error message + crash. Using

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

...did NOT work but I finally managed to fix it using this approach:

remove first:

```
sudo apt-get remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

then reinstall from new place:

```
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
```

The problem seems to be that the location of the font files has been changed on Sourceforge, and the location of the installer has not been updated (heard of using persistent URI:s anyone??). It's been explained here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/1371783/comments/45

Comment: Downvote: And this is exactly what rag2 has already been posted

Answer (score 2):

The msfonts server at sourceforge was down yesterday, its back now, had issues installing it in both Ubuntu and Arch but its fixed thankfully.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Options I am trying are to:

1. reinstall it, and
2. if it fails I will remove it.

**A.** I just reinstalled ttf-mscorefonts-installer with command
*sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer*

Outcome from the apt-get log in the terminal:

```
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
0% [Working]terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 56) > this->size() (which is 55)
Setting up ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2) ...
```

**B.** If I continue to see the below message, I plan to remove it with command: *sudo apt-get remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer*.

```
Failure to download extra data files

    The following packages requested additional data downloads after package installation, but the data could not be downloaded or could not be processed.

    ttf-mscorefonts-installer

    The download will be attempted again later, or you can try the download again now.  Running this command requires an active Internet connection.
```

Hope this answer helps. If you have a better answer, pls let me know. As solution B means MS core fonts will not be available for use.

Comment: Thanks, I did sudo apt-get remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer and it works. I hope that pop up won't show again, it's a shame that the fonts can't be installed...

Answer (score 1):

For me, the following worked like a charm:

```
sudo apt-get remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

then reinstall :

```
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
```

Comment: Downvote: And this is exactly what rag2 has already been posted